# My software center does not respond

Tags: 12.04, apt, software-center

I am using ubuntu 12.04.

I was trying to clean some applications installed before, so I opened software center by typing `software-center` into the command line. The window opened, and very soon it froze, completely not responding. I had to kill the process from command line in order to close the window. I removed software center and reinstalled it using `apt-get`, and it's all the same.

Currently I ran into a problem when updating from 12.04 to 14.04, and it seems to be software related. Link here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/681103/error-updating-from-12-04-to-14-04-lts

I am completely confused and suspect if they are related. Any suggestions on how to debug this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The cache needs be removed as well after removing the software. It's here:

```
sudo rm -r ~/.cache/software-center
```

Then reinstall. It worked.